# Codeigniter Update query issue

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, sql-update

I am making a student management system and I want to update record, all code works fine but update operation is not done also, all select elements like dropdown, radio button are not checked as data in database.

Code for controller:

```
//code to edit student record.
public function edit($stu_id){
$this->load->model('model_editstudent');
$data['r']=$this->model_editstudent ->get_student_row($stu_id);
$this->load->view('view_editstudent', $data);
}

#update query.
function update(){
    $stu_id=$this->input->post('stu_id');
    $data=array(
        'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'address'=>$this->input->post('address'),
        'sex'=>$this->input->post('sex'),
        'yop'=>$this->input->post('yop'),
        'interest'=>$this->input->post('interest'));
    $this->db->where('stu_id',$stu_id);
    $this->db->update('stu_record',$data);
    redirect('Student_Controller/');
}
```

Code for Model:

```
    <?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Model_EditStudent extends CI_Model{

    function get_student_row($stu_id){
    $this->db->where('stu_id',$stu_id);
    $query=$this->db->get('stu_record');
    #will return only one record(row)
    return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Code for view:

```
    <form method="POST" action='<?php echo site_url("student_controller/update"); ?>'>
<b>Student ID:</b><br>
<input type="text" Name="name" readonly value="<?php echo $r->stu_id ?>"><br><br>
<b>Name of the Student:</b><br>
<input type="text" Name="name" value="<?php echo $r->name ?>"><br><br>
<b>Address:</b><br>
<textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="22" ><?php echo $r->address ?></textarea><br><br>
<b>Gender:</b><br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="<?php if($r->sex=='Male') ?>">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="<?php if($r->sex=='Female') ?>">Female<br><br>
<b>Expected Year of Passing:</b><br>
<select name="yop" value="<?php echo $r->yop ?>">
<option value="0">Select Year</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select><br><br>
<b>Extra Curricular Interests:</b><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Sports"><label>Sports</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Programming"><label>Programming</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Arts"><label>Arts</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="interest" value="Music"><label>Music</label><br/>
<br><input type="submit" value="Update"> &nbsp 
<a href='<?php echo site_url('student_controller/'); ?>'>Cancel</a>
</form>
```

Comment: What error you get while doing update??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing change you select to

```
<select name="yop">
<option value="0">Select Year</option>
<option value="2010" <?php if($r->yop=="2010"){echo "selected=selected";}?>>2010</option>
<option value="2011" <?php if($r->yop=="2011"){echo "selected=selected";}?>>2011</option>
<option value="2012" <?php if($r->yop=="2012"){echo "selected=selected";}?>>2012</option>
<option value="2013" <?php if($r->yop=="2013"){echo "selected=selected";}?>>2013</option>
<option value="2014" <?php if($r->yop=="2014"){echo "selected=selected";}?>>2014</option>
<option value="2015" <?php if($r->yop=="2015"){echo "selected=selected";}?>>2015</option>
</select>
```

radio button to

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" <?php if($r->sex=='Male') echo "checked";?>">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" <?php if($r->sex=='Female') echo "checked"; ?>">Female<br><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, data is parsed in html form but I am not able to update the database can you tell me is there any error in my code. query is executed successfully but no changes are reflected in database?

Comment: can u check $_POST in controller as `print_r($_POST);exit;`

Comment: see `<input type="text" Name="name" readonly value="<?php echo $r->stu_id ?>">` change name to stu_id

Answer (score 0):

About your radio button, where does your if goes exactly ? You test if sex is male or female but nothing happens after that.

```
if($r->sex=='Male')
```

Also, I don't remember if uppercase matter or not but you use once 'student_controller' and once 'Student_Controller'. Did you get any error message ? Did you load the database... (just asking, since we don't have all the code, I am just assuming the worst). You should try to know if the form reach the update function once it is send. A silly echo inside your update function might do it for what I say...

I advise you to use the 'form_validation' library as well, in order to check the data coming from your post data and to sanitize it.

Something like :

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', '"Name of the Student"', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[22]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
// And you need to apply set_rules to each of your post data, like 'adress', 'sex', etc.

if($this->form_validation->run()):
  // Here goes your code, with the update query
endif;
redirect('Student_Controller/');
```

I don't know if it might help you but I hope so.